# Jest returning false positives for Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs

Having to write some Jest tests for Firebase functions and I'm running into a little trouble. Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do:

databaseUtils.js

```
function funcOne() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}

function funcTwo() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

index.js

```
exports.myTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await databaseUtils.funcOne();
    await databaseUtils.funcTwo();
    return res.status(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(403);
  }
});
```

index.test.js

```
describe('myTest', () => {
    it('test 1', async () => {
        const req = {}
        const res = {
            status: jest.fn()
        };
        await functions.myTest(req, res);
        expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200)
    });

    it('test 2', async () => {
        const req = {}
        const res = {
            status: code => {
                expect(code).toBe(403);
            }
        };
        await functions.myTest(req, res);
    });

    it('test 3', (done) => {
        const req = {}
        const res = {
            status: code => {
                expect(code).toBe(403);
                done();
            }
        };
        functions.myTest(req, res);
    });
})
```

When I run my tests, Test 1 fails while Test 2 and 3 pass, but with the wrong values:

```
JestAssertionError: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
    
    Expected: 403
    Received: 200
      matcherResult: {
        actual: 200,
        expected: 403,
        message: [Function],
        name: 'toBe',
        pass: false
      }
```

Been running around in circles trying to get this to work properly but I can't figure out, what am I doing wrong?

Once I've got this figured out I'd then mock `funcOne` / `funcTwo` to return a rejected promise so I can get the right status code.

Answer (score 0):

`onRequest` is promise-aware and expected to return a promise of the entire work it does. That there's a dangling promise inside `onRequest` callback is an antipattern.

It should be:

```
return auth.decodeToken(req)...
```

That there are raw promises with `then` and `catch` inside `async` contributes to the problem because `async..await` is sugar syntax that allows to avoid several common problems with promises. The said problem as well as nested promises could be avoided if this were written as:

```
try {
  const decodedToken = await auth.decodeToken(req);
  ...
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that and clearing it up! I've rewrote a dummy test and updated the original post with it using try/catch and I'm still getting the same sort of results.

Comment: This is true positive because you didn't do anything for the function to fail. Mock units that are responsible for the failure, since databaseUtils functions are used as methods they can be mocked without jest.mock, something like `jest.spyOn(databaseUtils, 'funcOne').mockRejectedValue('foo'); ... expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(403)`